# Binding a listbox inside popup inside tabcontrol header

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am creating a popup in the tab header I want to bind a list to the listbox inside the popup. but the binding is not working. This popup is inside the control template of tab control.

```xml
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ConnectionListDropDownButton}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ConnectionListDropDownButton, Path=IsChecked}"   AllowsTransparency="True"   PopupAnimation="Slide"    StaysOpen="False">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="ConnectionList" ItemsSource="{Binding tabItems}"  Background="White" SelectionChanged="ConnectionList_SelectionChanged" MaxHeight="300" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedIndex="-1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Here is my list need to be binded.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> tabItems { get; set; } = 
    new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
```

Comment: And where is `tabItems` defined?

Comment: What is not working about the binding? How is it behaving?

Comment: @mm8 The tabitems is defined in the usercontrol which contains the tabcontrol

Comment: @PeterBoone The tabitems has elements but the listbox do not display anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `Popup` to the parent control where the source property is defined and then bind the `ListBox` to the `Tag` property of the parent `Popup`:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ConnectionListDropDownButton}"
       IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ConnectionListDropDownButton, Path=IsChecked}"
       AllowsTransparency="True"
      PopupAnimation="Slide"
               StaysOpen="False"
               Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="ConnectionList"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Tag.tabItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Popup}}"
                         Background="White" SelectionChanged="ConnectionList_SelectionChanged" MaxHeight="300" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedIndex="-1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

You cannot bind the directly to the parent control from the `Popup` using a `RelativeSource`.